# Tab interface, having trouble unmounting components

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-redux, antd

Basically I have a tab interface using antd: https://ant.design/components/tabs/

Now, what i have is each tab loads the same component, but conditionally with different props, which works fine. So each tab, when i click on it loads its respective component.

Then on each component, im trying to do a reset whenever it unmounts.

The problem i have is that, when i click on the tabs, and i more from left to right ( if i click on a tab to my right ) the component unmounts fine. But if i click on a tab to the left ( moving from right to left ), the unmount event is not triggered.

I thought there was probably an issue with the plugin itself, but then i did a small demo online and the unmount worked fine on all cases.

So i figured there most be something wrong with my code, but i cant figure out what it is.

My tabs code looks like this:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={this.state.activeTab} onChange={this.onTabChange.bind(this)}>
                    <TabPane tab="Total" key={TAB_TOTAL}>
                        {(currentKey === TAB_TOTAL) &&
                            <ViewCommonContainer
                                budget={this.state.budgetSeasonId}
                                version={this.state.versionId}
                                view='total'
                            />
                        }
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Women" key={TAB_WOMEN}>
                        {(currentKey === TAB_WOMEN) &&
                            <ViewCommonContainer
                                budget={this.state.budgetSeasonId}
                                version={this.state.versionId}
                                view='women'
                            />
                        }
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Men" key={TAB_MEN}>
                        {(currentKey === TAB_MEN) &&
                            <ViewCommonContainer
                                budget={this.state.budgetSeasonId}
                                version={this.state.versionId}
                                view='men'
                            />
                        }
                    </TabPane>
...
```

And on  I have my componentDidUnmount() event, which works fine ONLY in this cases:

- Total Tab > Women or Men Tab
- Women Tab > Men Tab

Where I'm moving from left to right, but if i try any of this:

- Men Tab > Women or Total Tab
- Women Tab > Total Tab

Then the unmount doesnt happen for some reason.

I created an example online to test if the Antd Tabs implementation was causing this: https://codesandbox.io/s/k1wrm3v8v  But in that example the unmounting works fine.

Then i think something related to my Redux logic, but i'm a bit lost at the moment trying to figure this one out.

Basically on unmount im dipatching:

```
export const resetState = () => ({
   type: RESET_BUDGETS_VIEW,
});
```

And then i reset my state. But this dispatch action happend on unmount, which as i said earlier, doesnt happen all the time.

Also, i took a small screen share to demonstrate visually whats happening: https://media.giphy.com/media/xULW8MKZGRjhK2BoM8/giphy.gif  Quality is not as good, but you can somehow see that when i move left, the console log i have within my unmount method is called, but when i move left, nothing happens.

Also, this can happen as soon as i log into the page, so its not something that when i move from right to left it doesn't work because the component exists already.

Long post, i know. Let me know if i need to clarify this even more.

Thanks!

Comment: can you screen share via team viewer so that we can fix this together?

Comment: Not sure how i can do that, i can take another screengrab if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, using React functional components. I too had the same component in each tab with different props. I ended up NOT lazy loading ANY of the tabs when they are first clicked on. This is done using the `forceRender = {true}` prop on each on the TabPane components.

I understand this is not optimal from a data loading point of view.

Here is your code from the sand box made into functional components by the way. i used this to see how things were mounting and unmounting:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
function TestComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounting " + props.name);
    return () => {
      console.log("UNMounting " + props.name);
    };
  }, [props.name]);

  console.log("HOLA ", props.name);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

function Test(props) {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("1");
  console.log("Test was called. activeTab=" + activeTab);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Component 'Test' mounted.`);
    return () => console.log(`Compomnent 'Test' unmounting.`);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 24 }}>
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey={activeTab} onChange={(key) => setActiveTab(key)}>
        <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
          {activeTab === "1" && <TestComponent name="1" />}
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
          {activeTab === "2" && <TestComponent name="2" />}
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
          {activeTab === "3" && <TestComponent name="3" />}
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Tabs` has an property `activeKey`. This property handle this.